# Advice about expanding a wordmark into a full typeface - best practices for shoulders in letters

Tags: typefaces, font-design

Does anyone know of typefaces where the lowercase r has a shoulder, but the lowercase n does not? I've done a custom mark and it fits these requirements, but I'm confused as to how to expand the mark into an entire typeface. I used a shoulder on the lowercase m and now I'm thinking I might remove it. I haven't attached images as this it isn't publicly released yet but I'm curious as to best practices and advice on how to go forward.

[image: example of type treatment]

Comment: No best practice. Do what works for your needs.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you mean by an n with no shoulder, since shoulder means the top part which forms the whole curve of the n (http://www.typographydeconstructed.com/shoulder/). Do you mean it has a straight line instead of the curve on top? Even if it's not the typeface, can you post a sketch to see what you mean?

Comment: you're correct, to clarify i meant where the stem meets the shoulder, not sure if that's a crotch or not. i'll attach an image here:
[example](http://i.imgur.com/w1ew0QE.png)